# My view function is not returning, giving an internal server error 500

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, http-status-code-500, stable-diffusion

I am developing a web app using the Django framework. I am calling stable diffusion API in this view. It is working fine till the above line of return. I debugged using print statement and everything is working fine but I don't know why it's not rendering the next page. I have tried everything like returning a simple http response but the error is the same.
here is the view function:

```
def process_caption(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        content = request.POST.get('selected_caption')
        print(content,"+++++++++++++++++++++++++")
      # Process the selected box and its content here
        num_cols = 3
        num_rows = 4
        prompt = [content] * num_cols
        all_images = []
        print(prompt,"&&&&")
        print(all_images,"########")
        for i in range(num_rows):
            print("iiiiiiiiiiiii", i)
            images = pipe(prompt).images
            all_images.extend(images)
            print("iiiiiiiiiiiii", i)
        print("==============",len(all_images))
        for i in range(len(all_images)):
            all_images[i].save(f"/content/drive/MyDrive/SMARTY/media/{i}.png")
        print("every thing went well ")
        print(all_images)

        return render(request, 'images.html', {'images': all_images})
        print("dsad")
    else:
        return render(request, 'caption.html')
```

Dsad is not printed. everything else is printed.

I tried rendering an http response but of no help. the template it should render if it works the way i want is images.html where images are displayed

Comment: Could you share the traceback ?

Comment: there is no traceback it just gives an internal server error on the browser.

Comment: In that case, if you can afford it, you should set the DEBUG flag to True in your conf to get some details including a traceback

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the issue is related to saving images section, you can comment that section and check if it works or not, if the issue is related to this you can use threading tosave images like this:

```py
import threading

def save_images(images):
    for i, image in enumerate(images):
        image.save(f"/content/drive/MyDrive/SMARTY/media/{i}.png")

def process_caption(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        content = request.POST.get('selected_caption')
        num_cols = 3
        num_rows = 4
        prompt = [content] * num_cols
        all_images = []
        for i in range(num_rows):
            images = pipe(prompt).images
            all_images.extend(images)
        # Save images asynchronously
        thread = threading.Thread(target=save_images, args=(all_images,))
        thread.start()

        return render(request, 'images.html', {'images': all_images})
    else:
        return render(request, 'caption.html')
```

Comment: The images are now getting saved, but the problem is the view does not smoothly continue to images.html page. I can access the page when written on URL bar but does not display on its own as it should after saving images then return to images page.